# Accessing 2D array in unmanaged vector of vectors (C++)

Tags: .net, c++, arrays

I am working with a set of unmanaged C++ API functions from within a managed C++ module.  I obtain a matrix of `double` values (`std::vector<std::vector<double>>`) from one API function and need to pass the matrix as a `double**` parameter to another API function. I can always repackage the original matrix into a new `double[][]` by copying elements. However, I want to avoid this, as it gets too expensive with the large matrix and and my method being called frequently.

Accessing the elements of the original returned matrix must be easy, and I wrote a couple of simple template methods to do that (see below), however they are not working and I am a bit puzzled why. I can access individual elements of the array from inside `Method1` and `Method2`, but the `T**` returned from either of methods points is unusable as it points somewhere else. Could someone help me out, please?

```
T** Method1(vector<vector<T>> vvT)
{
    int size = vvT.size();
    if (size == 0)
        return NULL;
    pin_ptr<T> pin_p1 = &(vvT[0][0]);
    T* p1 = pin_p1;
    T** p2 = &p1;
    return p2;
}

T** Method2(vector<vector<T>> vvT)
{
    int size = vvT.size();
    if (size == 0)
        return NULL;
    vector<T*> ptrs(size);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        ptrs[i] = &(vvT[i][0]);
    }
    T** result = &ptrs[0];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: To be clear, by `vector` you mean `std::vector` and not `cliext::vector`, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating p1 on the stack, as a local variable, and then returning a pointer to it.  It will subsequently be wiped out during or after function return as the memory gets reused.  Try returning p1 instead and have the function return the pin_ptr, because when the pin_ptr goes out of scope the memory gets unpinned anyway.

A similar scenario would be this:

```
int* foo()
{
    int x = 2;
    return &x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you're passing your `vector` by value, so the addresses you store no longer point to valid memory as soon as the function returns and said `vector` goes out of scope. (The same is true of the address you return from `Method2`, as `ptrs` goes out of scope.) If you want a `double**` (as opposed to a `const double**`), then you need to pass your `vector` by non-const reference.

The other problem is that you have no way of returning a `double**` without allocating any memory and consequently forcing someone to `delete` it later. Your `Method2` implemention is almost the correct approach -- rather than deal with the "*who's responsibility is it to `delete` this memory?*" issue, it's significantly easier to simply return a `std::vector<double*>` and when the `double**` is needed, take the address of the 0th element of *that* vector instead.

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T*> Method3(std::vector<std::vector<T> >& vvT)
{
    std::vector<T*> ret;
    for (size_t i = 0, i_max = vvT.size(); i != i_max; ++i)
        ret.push_back(&vvT[i][0]);
    return ret;
}

// ...

std::vector<std::vector<double> > vec = api1();
std::vector<double*> addresses = Method3(vec);
api2(!addresses.empty() ? &addresses[0] : 0);
```

Note that the stored pointers may potentially point to invalid memory as soon as the `vector` passed to `Method3` is modified (i.e., resized or destroyed). Also note that `pin_ptr` has no place here, as it's for pinning the elements of a managed object and `std::vector<>` is not a managed type.